# javascript 配列をカテゴリ化したい

Tags: javascript

変数aはもともと配列という前提で、この配列をオブジェクトにまとめたいのですが、うまい方法が思いつきません。Object.assignだと代入になってしまいます。ご教示いただければ幸いです。

```
let a = 'Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Kanda, 1, 佐藤 | Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Otemachi, 1, 鈴木 | Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Otemachi, 2, 伊藤 | Japan, Tokyo, Minato, Akasaka, 1, 橋本 | Japan, Tokyo, Minato, Akasaka, 2, 萩原'

a = a.split(' | ')
let obj = {}
for(let y of a){
    y = y.split(", ")
    y = y.reduceRight((pre, cur) => {
        return {[cur]:pre}
    })
    console.log(y)
    Object.assign(obj, y)
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: 「オブジェクトにまとめる」とはどういう結果になって欲しいのでしょうか? 具体例があるとわかりやすいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 {Japan : {Tokyo : {Chiyoda : {Kanda : {1 : 佐藤, 2 : 萩原}}}}}　　こういった感じです。

Comment: なるほど、オブジェクトを再帰的にマージしたいわけですね。最後の項目だけ異なるケースはありえますか? 例 'Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Kanda, 1, 佐藤 | Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Kanda, 1, 鈴木'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

オブジェクトを再帰的にマージする簡単な方法は思いつかなかったので、`mergeObjectOnto()`は地道なコードとなっています。

ツリーの末端でキーが衝突した場合はとりあえず配列化するようにしました。

実行結果:

```
{
  "Japan": {
    "Tokyo": {
      "Chiyoda": {
        "Kanda": {
          "1": "佐藤"
        },
        "Otemachi": {
          "1": "鈴木",
          "2": "伊藤"
        }
      },
      "Minato": {
        "Akasaka": {
          "1": "橋本",
          "2": [
            "萩原",
            "田中"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const source = 'Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Kanda, 1, 佐藤 | ' +
    'Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Otemachi, 1, 鈴木 | ' +
    'Japan, Tokyo, Chiyoda, Otemachi, 2, 伊藤 | ' +
    'Japan, Tokyo, Minato, Akasaka, 1, 橋本 | ' +
    'Japan, Tokyo, Minato, Akasaka, 2, 萩原 | ' +
    'Japan, Tokyo, Minato, Akasaka, 2, 田中';

const rows = source.split(' | ');
let obj = {};
for (const row of rows) {
  const columns = row.split(", ");
  const nestedColumns = columns.reduceRight((pre, cur) => {
    return {[cur]:pre};
  });
  console.log(nestedColumns);
  mergeObjectOnto(nestedColumns, obj);
}
// 結果表示
console.log(obj);
document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

function mergeObjectOnto(src, dest) {
  for (const key in src) {
    if (!dest.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      dest[key] = src[key];
    } else if (!(src[key] instanceof Object) || !(dest[key] instanceof Object)) {
      // オブジェクトではないものが衝突した場合、とりあえず配列に詰めておく。
      if (dest[key] instanceof Array) {
        dest[key].push(src[key])
      } else {
        dest[key] = [dest[key], src[key]];
      }
    } else {
      mergeObjectOnto(src[key], dest[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさに求めていたものです。大変参考になりました。